# Custom listView row with checkbox & savings check marks on rotation

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

**So situation is:**
- listview rows have a layout that contains a checkbox (and a couple o textviews)
- i set the id this way.. like in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

```
<CheckBox 
       android:id="@android:id/text1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content/>
```

- and below other objects involved: my adapter:

  private class SelectCartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <SelectCartListItem>
  ...
- and my SelectCartListItem which implements Checkable!

  public class SelectCartListItem implements OnClickListener, Checkable
  ...
- and listview with multiple choice
- and some listview settings in onCreate:

  m_ListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  m_ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

So obviously i want to save save the checks on rotation .. all my trials had been unsuccessfull

This prints no ids!

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle args) {
    Log.d(">>>onSaveInstanceState","<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    long[] toSave = m_ListView.getCheckItemIds();//TODO: save!
    for(int i=0;i<toSave.length;i++){
        Log.d(">>>>"+i+"]",toSave[i]+"");
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(args);
}
```

So what am I missing.. ideas.. anyone?

UPDATE: my solution: i created a static map inside a new object Map<String, Boolean>..which will contain my check/uncheck situation + static methods to add/getCheck state.. it is not that pretty but works...

Answer (score 0):

//add the array to the bundle

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle args) {
    Log.d(">>>onSaveInstanceState","<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    long[] toSave = m_ListView.getCheckItemIds();//TODO: save!
     //add it to the bundle 
   args.putLongArray("mycheck",toSave );
    for(int i=0;i<toSave.length;i++){
        Log.d(">>>>"+i+"]",toSave[i]+"");
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(args);
}
```

and get them in `onRestoreInstanceState()`

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 Long [] arr = savedInstanceState.getLongArray("mycheck");
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is stating that the returned array is empty, so saving it into the bundle isn't going to help much.

Comment: correct Aleks G! + that i am working with fragment and no onRestoreInstanceState... but that not the problem i use onActivityCreated... So this should be on focus: m_ListView.getCheckItemIds(); <<< doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the view's TAGs to 1 if checked 0 if unchecked and look it up inside your adapter.